# UnicodeDecodeError when altering table

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, sqlite

I'm trying to do automatic `alter table` - adding column when it is necessary. The problem is that I've started to getting `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I don't understand why this error is raising. Why it wants to use `'ascii'` charset.

I've tried to `print attr.__class__` which prints `unicode`.
I've already tried to `attr.decode('utf-8')` but still the same problem is raising.

**LINE:**

```
self.cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN {} TEXT""".format(attr))
```

**RETURNS:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top of the  file.

What should I do in this case? Is it possible to find out which encoding is used?

EDIT: If I rewrite the alter not to use variables, it works.

Comment: Like a lot of Unicode-related issues, this would probably either go away or at least give you a better error message if you were using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from unicode to bytes you use `encode`, not `decode`.

Alternatively, make the SQL string unicode:

```
self.cur.execute(u"""ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN {} TEXT""".format(attr))
```